# Boost ASIO async_read_some

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am having difficulties in implementing a simple TCP server. The following code is taken from [boost::asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html), "Http Server 1" to be precise.

```
void connection::start() {
    socket_.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
            boost::bind(
                &connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
            )
        );
}
void connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!e && bytes_transferred)    {
                std::cout << " " << bytes_transferred <<"b" << std::endl;
                data_.append(buffer_.data(), buffer_.data()+bytes_transferred);

                //(1) what here?                
                socket_.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), 
                    boost::bind(
                        &connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                    )
                ); 

            }
            else// if (e != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            {
                std::cout << data_ << std::endl;
                connection_manager_.stop(shared_from_this());
            }
        }
```

In the original code the `buffer_` is big enough to keep the entire request. It's not what I need. I've changed the size to 32bytes.

The server compiles and listens at port 80 of localhost, so I try to connect to it via my web browser.

Now if the statement (1) is commented-out, then only the first 32bytes of the request are read and the connection hangs. Web browser keeps waiting for the response, the server does.. I dont know what.

If (1) is uncommented, then the entire request is read (and appeded to `data_`), but it never stops - I have to cancel the request in my browser and only then does the `else { }` part run - I see my request on stdout.

**Question 1:** How should I handle a large request?
**Question 2:** How should I cache the request (currently I append the buffer to a string)?
**Question 3:** How can I tell that the request is over? In HTTP there always is a response, so my web-browser keeps waiting for it and doesnt close the connection, but how can my server know that the request is over (and perhaps close it or reply some "200 OK")?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose browser send you 1360 bytes of data, you say `asio` to read some data into your buffer that you say it only have 32 bytes.
then first time that you call it your handler will be called with 32 bytes start of data. here if you comment (1) then browser try to send rest of its data(actually browser already sent it and it is in the OS buffer that wait for you to peek it from there) and you are possibly blocked behind `io_service::run` for some miracle!!

if you uncomment (1) as you say your loop started, you read first block, then next and another and ... until the data that the browser sent finished, but after that when you say `asio` to read some more data it will wait for some more data that never come from the browser( since browser already sent its information and is waiting for your answer ) and when you cancel the request from the browser, it will close its socket and then your handler will be called whith an error that say I can't read more data, since the connection is closed.!!

but what you should do here to make it work is: you should learn `HTTP` format and thus know what is the data that your browser sent to you and provide a good answer for it and then your communication with the client will be proceeded. in this case end of buffer is `\r\n\r\n` and when you see it you shouldn't read any more data, you should process what you read till now and then send a response to the browser.

Comment: If only I was using HTTP I'd stick to some ending-pattern. But I am using TCP in general, and it works with HTTP by accident I'd say ;-)

Comment: in any case I describe your problem, in any protocol you should know when to listen and when to speak. in the situation of the example browser wait for your answer and you possibly wait for a miracle. TCP is a transport system not a protocol( of course it is a protocol but not for you or me for those who use raw sockets or want to implement TCP/IP ) and you should know format of each protocol that you want to implement and there is no global solution that work with any protocol

Comment: Okay. What about sending a serializable object, like in the [Serialization example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html). If I send an object, then boost will automatically handle size control?

Comment: in case of serialization you have 2 steps: first) read data from the socket and then) call boost::serialization to deserialize the buffer. so first you should know when stop reading. this is when I say for every protocol you should know format of it, even for a custom protocol that you design it for your own purpose, I can advise a simple trick. in the send side serialize object into a buffer and you know the size of the buffer then embed this size in start of sending buffer and in receive side first read size and then read data up to specified size and deserialize it!! it's simple